# Сломался вид админки в джанго

Tags: python, django, django-admin

На всех категориях появляется сайдбар с домашней страницы админки. Происходит только на хосте, на дев-сервере все впорядке.[image: страница из админки]

Обновлял статику, менял бд, переустанавливал джангу на сервере - не помогло.

Comment: смотрите, что меняли:    css, js, html

Comment: Проверьте параметр DEBUG в файле settings.py. Если вы запускаете на локалхосте с дебагом False, может быть такая ошибка + статик файлы могут вообще не подтягиваться. Так же попробуйте полностью почистить кеш браузера. Если вы не писали свои html, css, js файлы, удалите папку статик и запустите команду python manage.py collectstatic. И ко всему прочему, проверьте ваши static_root и static_url. Если всё равно будет ошибка, приложите свой код, что бы можно было выявить ошибку + код ошибки